How do I get typescript hover docs working with JSX props in Vim 9?
Currently using coc.nvim ShowDocumentation() for my K keybinding to show docs for members but this doesn't seem to expose typescript props for JSX elements - have to write a whole duplicate JSDOC section.
Also tab completion for JSX properties doesn't work.
Anybody have good JSX docs and autocomplete working with coc.nvim or another Vim plugin on Vim 9?

The coc.nvim is only a bridge to the LSP server. I suppose the weakness is not to find the coc.nvim but in the underlying LSP server.
